# Discount curve from spot rates for bond pricing

Tags: bond, discount-factor-curve

I have a bond with the following cash flow and maturity:

```
Cash flow vector    Maturity
4                   0.479452055
4                   1.479452055
4                   2.479452055
4                   3.479452055
104                 4.479452055
```

I want to derive the price by discounting using the spot curve (see Excel-File for exact values) per 2015-12-31 and a credit spread of 0,054430033:

```
 Spot Curve   Maturity
 -0.8%         1
 -0.8%         2
 -0.8%         3
 -0.7%         4
 -0.5%         5
```

I tried this in the [Excel-Spreadsheet (over here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awd0ml3s8p5zs7w/AT0000A10J83.xls?dl=0), however the prices I calculate differ from the price of my bond valuation engine where 98.22 is provided (in two programmes independently). I guess the discount factors I use are wrong. Yet I do not know how to construct the proper discount curve with these inputs. Can you please point me to the right direction?

---

**Update:**
I have been thinking about my issue and spotted a maturity mismatch since the spot curve is provided for maturity 1 to 10 whilst my first cash flow is at 0.479 - probably this is a problem as well?